# Создать список AD групп в которых состоит пользователь

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите пытаюсь создать список пользователей + название ad группы в которых они состоят.

Должно выводить: `VPipkin: 'test','test2'` если в 2 (определенных) группах состоит или `VPipkin: 'test'` если в одной.
Как правильно прописать чтобы выводилось `VPipkin: 'test','test2'`

```
#Условия поиска
    conn.search(AD_SEARCH_TREE, '(|(memberOf=cn=test,ou=GIS,ou=Resource_Access_Groups_Auto,ou=Groups,dc=d,dc=a, dc=c)(memberOf=cn=test_2,ou=GIS,ou=Resource_Access_Groups_Auto,ou=Groups,dc=d,dc=a,dc=c))',
                attributes = ['sAMAccountName','sn','givenName','mail','displayName','memberof'])

#Формируем список пользователей из AD групп
    name={}
    for entri in conn.entries:
        for cn in entri.memberof:
            if re.search(r'CN=test', cn):
                name[entri.sAMAccountName[0]]='test'
            if re.search(r'CN=test2\b', cn):
                name[entri.sAMAccountName[0]]='test2'
            if re.search(r'CN=test\b', cn) and re.search(r'CN=test2', cn):
                name[entri.sAMAccountName[0]]=['test','test2']
            
    return name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
name={}
for entri in conn.entries:
name[entri.sAMAccountName[0]] = []
    for cn in entri.memberof:
        if re.search(r'CN=test\b', cn):
            name[entri.sAMAccountName[0]].append('test')
        if re.search(r'CN=test\b', cn):
            name[entri.sAMAccountName[0]].append('test2')
```

Comment: Да спасибо то что нужно только ``name[entri.sAMAccountName[0]] = []`` после ``for entri in conn.entries:``

Comment: а, ну да, не увидел, что там переменная из цикла